# Itertools vs Nested Loops Performance

Tags: python, performance, loops, python-itertools

I have to generate all the 2-pair combinations of items in a list. Now, I know of two ways to accomplish this: nested for-loops, and python's built-in *itertools*:

```
from itertools import combinations

foo = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in xrange(len(foo)):
    for j in xrange(i + 1, len(foo)):
        print foo[i], foo[j]

for c in  combinations(foo, 2):
    print c
```

My question is: are there any significant advantages to using one over the other?

Comment: The second one looks WAY nicer and is probably faster. You can easily write a program to test the speed, just set `foo = range(1000)` to make it a good test.

Comment: `print foo[i], foo[j]` doesn't actually do the same thing as `print c`. The first version prints `foo[i]` and `foo[j]` separated by a space, while the second prints a tuple.

Comment: @user2357112, I was thinking about that; I've changed it to save a tuple in a list, and am running timeit on both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I went ahead and used Python's *timeit* to measure the runtimes, modifying the first loop as @user2357112 suggested:

```
import timeit
from itertools import combinations

foo = [i for i in xrange(0, 1000)]    

def loop_test():
    combos = []
    for i in xrange(len(foo)):
        for j in xrange(i + 1, len(foo)):
            combos.append((foo[i], foo[j]))    

def iter_test():
    combos = []
    for c in combinations(foo, 2):
        combos.append(c)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print timeit.timeit('loop_test()', setup='from __main__ import loop_test', number=1000)
    print timeit.timeit('iter_test()', setup='from __main__ import iter_test', number=1000)
```

With an output:

```
59.1836869717
45.6625859737
```

Interestingly, it appears as though *itertools* is in fact faster than the nested loops.