# How to merge list to get the mentioned output below?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have the following code:

```py
import itertools

host = ["computer1", "computer2"]

variants = [".some.domain.com", ".another.domain.com"]

for host in host:

    merged_list = "\n".join([host + variants_index for variants_index in variants])

    merged_list = merged_list.split()

    united = list(itertools.chain(merged_list))

    print(united)
```

**But I want the following output:**
['computer1.some.domain.com', 'computer1.another.domain.com', 'computer2.some.domain.com', 'computer2.another.domain.com']

**What I am gettin now, it is this:**

['computer1.some.domain.com', 'computer1.another.domain.com']

['computer2.some.domain.com', 'computer2.another.domain.com']

How to merge all of them together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use itertools product

```
from itertools import product

result = [a+b for a, b in product(host, variants)]

#result: ['computer1.some.domain.com', 'computer1.another.domain.com', 'computer2.some.domain.com', 'computer2.another.domain.com']
```

Comment: Yeah, this works too - `itertools.product` is roughly equivalent to a nested for loop. The docs note that it has to entirely consume both inputs so I don't see a _strong_ reason to prefer one over the other, though concision counts for something. The `repeat` keyword option for `product` is a nice option to have as well.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper--the main advantage is the speed for larger arrays since [itertools implemented in c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c).  Since Python loops are much slower than C loops itertools wins out on larger arrays.

Comment: Thanks for all of you! <3

Comment: A quick check is getting me conflicting results for different people using `timeit` to compare some itertools approaches vs. nested lists - it looks like it depends on the size of the input sequences, possibly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584544/2337736 vs https://stackoverflow.com/a/37355093/2337736 (only roughly equivalent to product). I'd probably want to profile on the expected data, though of course either approach is plenty fast enough for this example.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper--right, the overhead kills the speed advantage for smaller data sizes.  You see this in Numpy for instance where the overhead negates the speed advantage on small arrays.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper--by the way I get a slighly faster result when using a list comprehension rather than the nested lists i.e. `[host + variant for host in hosts for variant in variants]`

Comment: Yeah, I tested on `range(100)` for both inputs and got `product` coming out at just over half the time of the nested version. And it's faster even down to `range(10)`. It's significantly slower if you try to iterate over the product result rather than just using it in a comprehension (as you did), so that may be what's throwing off that first comparison link. `product` did come out slower on my machine for `range(2)`, which matches this input, but of course the difference at that input size is far too small to matter.

Comment: And just for completeness's sake I'll agree that the nested comprehension beats both the `product` solution and the nested `for` solution on my machine at all inputs I tried, though it's a marginal difference vs product at 1000x1000 and probably comes even closer above that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you don't even need `itertools`, and as pointed out in comments on another answer, it is even faster (than for loops or `itertools.product`)

```
united = [h + v for h in host for v in variants]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be simpler with a plain nested for loop:

```
united = []
for host in hosts:
    for variant in variants:
        united.append(host + variant)
```

You could collapse that to a list comprehension but I find nested list comprehensions generally more trouble than they're worth. Though profiling does indicate that they're faster, especially on large inputs.